# Nokia is Superfluous in Lumia Tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I am new here and noticed that some of the tags used are very ambiguous in nature like,  [8.0-apollo](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8.0-apollo), [nokia-lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia) and such. [nokia-lumia](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia) can be shortened to "*lumia+BrandName*" such as [lumia-920](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-920). I don't see any need for mentioning *nokia* in the tag.

Just my two cents. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, see also http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/193/whats-with-the-windows-8-tag and deeper links

Comment: @akid - But nothing seems to have come of it. How do we go about it? I don't have the reputation yet to go about changing tags. But anyways, we need to have a discussion towards a solution first.

Comment: @row1 - Appreciate the response. You can edit this question as you may deem fine and make it lumia specific. No problems with me. Also, the linked question has answers but hasn't really contributed to any tangible change in the user behavior here. So, I am not sure if this question was entirely unwarranted.

Comment: @Mohit I have updated your question to just be about Nokia. I have made http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/173/how-should-we-form-tags-for-specific-wp-versions a featured question, so give it a little bit more time and then we can action it. So please upvote answers in that post or add your own answer. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 4):

I think having the manufacturers name is actually a good thing. The Android sister site seems to also do this and not have any synonyms e.g. https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/samsung-galaxy-s-3/synonyms and https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/htc-desire/synonyms

While I can agree that for Lumia it is currently obvious that it is a Nokia, for other manufacturers with short product names it would be less clear e.g. I think the synonym [8x](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8x) should be removed, especially since there is a similar and unrelated [7.x](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.x). This might not currently be a problem for Windows Phone as it seems to just be Nokia releasing phones these days, but if more products started appearing with generic names it would become a bit messy.