# Some tag synonym requests

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I believe there's consensus to use the manufacturer name in device-specific tags, so I'm requesting the following tags to be turned into synonyms:

- [lumia-520](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-520) → synonym of [nokia-lumia-520](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia-520)
- [lumia-925](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-925) → synonym of [nokia-lumia-925](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia-925)

Also, [lumia-810](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lumia-810) should be renamed to [nokia-lumia-810](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nokia-lumia-810).

Comment: Related: http://meta.windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/205/nokia-is-superfluous-in-lumia-tags
I would personally have no synonyms and just have the full name.

Comment: Just renaming the tags is also fine by me, although I understand generally it's a good idea to have common variants as synonyms, to prevent the duplicate tags from being created again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the consensus in the current tags, and the voting on [Nokia is Superfluous in Lumia Tags](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/nokia-is-superfluous-in-lumia-tags), I'll reverse the synonym on lumia-520, and set up the other two...